# remote shell call with awk from perl script

Tags: perl, shell, awk, rsh

I'm trying to execute commands on a remote host from a perl script.

```
$check = `rsh host1 "df -k /backup/|tail -1|awk \'{print \$5}\'"`;
print $check
```

But awk returns me the whole string instead of one column.

```
/dev/md/dsk/d10      4133838 1936684 2155816    48%    /
```

I need only

```
48%
```

Looks like there is an issue in escaping but don't know what exactly wrong. Please help.

Comment: is this working? Where is your ending double quotes? Wht are you escaping quotes and $?

Comment: I'm unsure, but try removing the quotes around the command. i.e: `$check = \`rsh host1 df -k /backup/|tail -1|awk '{print \$5}'\`;` should do

Comment: That is not Perl code. Perl uses `print`, not `echo`. It might be php.

Comment: indeed should be print. updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use `qx` with the single quote as a delimiter instead, so that Perl variables are not interpolated:

```
$check = qx'rsh host1 "df -k /backup/|tail -1|awk \"{print \$5}\""';
```

I have used double quotes around the awk command, so it is still necessary to escape the `$5` to prevent it from being interpreted as a shell variable.

If you are happy to run `tail` and `awk` on the local machine, you can remove the double quotes:

```
$check = qx'rsh host1 df -k /backup/|tail -1|awk "{print \$5}"';
```

This results in more data being copied back from the remote machine, which may or may not be a problem.

Alternatively, you could split the output using Perl and avoid the problem entirely:

```
$check = (split /\s+/, qx'rsh host1 "df -k /backup/|tail -1"')[4];
```

Comment: What an awesome answer! Thank you for your tips.